# How to use checkbox in Github markdown?

Tags: github, markdown

I want to include a checkbox in my PR template which I thought could be achieved by html since Github markdown supports it. It did work fine on VScode but when I pushed it, seems like its broken in Github as it doesn't render the checkboxes. I can think that some people will suggest to use either this:

```
- [ ] Uranus
- [ ] Neptune
- [ ] Comet Haley
```

or any other solution that you can think of with the emojis. The problem is that none of them really helps to me since I want people to simply interact with the checkboxes rather then having them to get in to markdown and insert some text there in order to be rendered as checkbox. Any idea what could be the way around?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only user Markdown based checkboxes on GitHub.

If you have an HTML form which contains a checkbox, after the user "checks" the box the form would need to be submitted to a server and then state would need to be updated on the server. GitHub does not have a mechanism to do that.

Additionally, GitHub passes all user provided content through a very rigorous sanitizer which removes many types of content. I expect that they would remove any and all form elements from user provided content as forms would be an easy way for a malicious user to execute attacks of various types.

And then there is the fact that any content included in your issue templates would be displayed to the user within a textarea as raw source. The user would see `<input type="checkbox">` rather than a rendered checkbox. And then the user would need to edit it to include the `checked` attribute: `<input type="checkbox" checked>`.

Therefore, the only solution is to use Markdown based checkboxes. The user needs to edit the Markdown by adding an `x` inside the brackets to reflect that an item was "checked". Needless to say, that is much easier than adding `checked` to raw HTML. And it doesn't require a form to be submitted or a server to receive the submission and save the new state.

```
* [x] checked
* [ ] not checked
```

Comment: Hey Waylan, thanks for investing time to reply. I accept this as an answer but there is some more stuff to add. I have noticed that once you use the markdown checkboxes you can actually check or uncheck them after its published which means if you use the markdown checkboxes and switch to review window you won't be able to check or uncheck them, while after submit you actually can. That's why I was a bit confused but right now my team is able to check or uncheck or even order them thanks to flexibility provided by Github. Thanks for the effort again!